# How to use regexp on the results of a sub query?

Tags: mysql, regex, subquery, pattern-matching

I have two tables.

User 
which has **id** and **phone number**

---

**id**  **phone_no**

1 ----  9912678

2 ----  9912323

3 ----  9912366

---

Admission Table , which has **id** **phone number**

**id** **phone_no**

6 --- 991267823

7 --- 991236621

8 --- 435443455

9 --- 243344333

I want to find all the **phone number** of **Admission's** table which has same pattern as **users** table and **update** it in users table.

So i am trying this

```
select phone_no  from admission where phone_no REGEXP (SELECT phone_no
FROM  `users` AS user
WHERE user.phone_no REGEXP  '^(99)+[0-9]{8}')
```

But i am getting this error **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

Looking for help.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "has same pattern"? Guessing from your examples, is it actually "starts with"?

Comment: User's table and admission's table both has same phone numbers starting with 99 but user's table missing trailing 2 digit. First I want to filter all these number from admission's table '^[99]+[0-9]{8}'  and then match user's phone no 9912678 with admission's phone no 991267823

Comment: if i query data for user's table formatted in this manner   '9912678|9912323|9912366'  the query executes fine but i don't know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: What should the pattern '[99]+' mean? It is equal to '[9]+' and that is equal to '9+'. Maybe you mean '(99)+' or just '99'.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yes you are right. It would be '(99)+'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these queries:

```sql
SELECT a.phone_no
FROM admission a
JOIN users u on a.phone_no LIKE concat(u.phone_no, '__')
WHERE u.phone_no REGEXP  '^(99)+[0-9]+$'
```

or

```sql
SELECT a.phone_no
FROM admission a
JOIN users u on a.phone_no REGEXP concat('^', u.phone_no, '[0-9]{2}$')
WHERE u.phone_no REGEXP  '^(99)+[0-9]+$'
```

If the number of "trailing digits" is not fixed, you can also use:

```sql
LIKE concat(u.phone_no, '%')
```

or

```sql
REGEXP concat('^', u.phone_no, '[0-9]*$')
```

But in this case you might need to use `SELECT DISTICT a.phone_no` if it is possible that a `users.phone_no` is a subsequence of an other `users.phone_no` (e.g. 99123 and 991234).

**Update**

After running some tests with 10K rows for users table and 100K rows for admission table i came to the following query:

```sql
SELECT a.phone_no
FROM admission a
JOIN users u 
    ON  a.phone_no >= u.phone_no
    AND a.phone_no < CONCAT(u.phone_no, 'z')
    AND a.phone_no LIKE CONCAT(u.phone_no, '%')
    AND a.phone_no REGEXP CONCAT('^', u.phone_no, '[0-9]*$')
WHERE   u.phone_no LIKE  '99%'
    AND u.phone_no REGEXP  '^(99)+[0-9]*$'
UNION SELECT 0 FROM (SELECT 0) dummy WHERE 0
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c905b/22)

This way you can use `REGEXP` and still have great performance. This query executes almost instantly in my test case.

Logically you only need the REGEXP conditions. But on bigger tables the query might time out. Using a LIKE condition will filter the result set before REGEXP check. But even using LIKE the query doesn't perform very well. For some reason MySQL doesn't use a range check for the join. So i added an explicit range check:

```sql
    ON  a.phone_no >= u.phone_no
    AND a.phone_no < CONCAT(u.phone_no, 'z')
```

With this check you can remove the LIKE condition from the JOIN part.

The UNION part is a replacement for DISTICT. MySQL seems to translate DISTINCT into a GROUP BY statement, which doesn't perform well. Using UNION with an empty result set i force MySQL to remove duplicates after the SELECT. You can remove that line, if you use a fixed number of trailing digits.

You can adjust the REGEXP patterns to your needs:

```sql
...
    AND a.phone_no REGEXP CONCAT('^', u.phone_no, '[0-9]{2}$')
...
    AND u.phone_no REGEXP  '^(99)+[0-9]{8}$'
...
```

If you only need REGEXP to check the length of the phone_no, you can also use a LIKE condition with the '_' placeholder.

```sql
    AND a.phone_no LIKE CONCAT(u.phone_no, '__')
...
    AND u.phone_no LIKE '99________$'
```

or combine a LIKE condition with a STR_LENGTH check.

Comment: Joining with `LIKE` without using `DISTINCT` will return duplicates, better use `EXISTS` instead of joining the table.

Comment: Thanks @maraca. However `DISTINCT` is only needed, if the number of "trailing digits" is not fixed.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel your first query returning empty result, 2nd query returning more values then admission table has and third one working fine. Thanks

Comment: i just updated my question , would you please help about updating values on users table?

Comment: @shuvrow, if you want to update users phone_no with the matches found in admission table - then more information is needed. However you can allways join a table with a subquery in an UPDATE statement. Maybe this one will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588710/mysql-update-query-with-sub-query

Comment: i did it ... too much pressure and ended up asking help from you. Tx :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want, I did some improvements ([SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/222c5/12/0)):

```
select * from admission a where exists (
  select * from (
     select substr(phone_no, 1, 7) pn from users where phone_no REGEXP '^99[0-9]{5}'
  ) o where a.phone_no like concat(o.pn, '%')
)
```

I had to modify the regex to get any matches. If the length is fixed the second check can easily be done with `like`. We look in the `user` table to see if there `exists` any `phone_no` that matches the criteria for the admission number we are currently looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind regex. Do a simple join using `like`

```
select distinct a.phone_no
from user u
join admission a on a.phone_no like concat(u.phone_no, '%')
where u.phone_no like '99%'
```

The `distinct` keyword is only needed if there are either duplicate numbers in the `admission` table, and/or in the `user` table. Otherwise, it can be omitted.

Comment: Sorry, but as is the query is wrong and has exactly the problem he is complaining about: the phone numbers will be multiplied (unless you do a distinct).

Comment: @maraca you are incorrect. The error OP is getting has nothing to do with returning duplicate rows from the result; it is due to OP's *subquery* returning multiple rows when used as a single-valued result in the query. Using `distinct` in OP's query would not make OP's error go away. Using `distinct` in my query would only be needed if there were duplicates in the raw data (I have updated my answer to explain that).

Comment: @maraca again, I disagree with everything you have said. To be clear, if 2 admissions numbers both match (ie start with) the same user number, they are both expected in the output according to OP's requirements. As I said before, duplication in the output can only occur if there are actual duplicates in either of the tables. Further, `like` is entirely appropriate, as the semantic is "starts with", which is easiest, best and clearest expressed as `like 'prefix%'`. Using `exists` will perform very badly, as it must execute the subquery once for every row, where as `like` uses only 1 pass.

Comment: Well I thought it's unclear, so let me give an example, user table 9923, 992 and the other table 99234, 99235... no duplicates, still returns both numbers twice... I really see no reason for joining when you try to filter the admission table it belongs in the where clause in my opinion, otherwise it makes things needlessly complicated.

Comment: @maraca ok. all examples posted had all numbers within a table having the same length as each other, which I assumed to be the rule. If that is not the case, then you are correct about getting duplicates.