# mysql update query throwing syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql-update, syntax-error

I am trying to update user information (phone number) but mysql showing syntax error.

Here is the query for showing all data (**phone number**)

```
select distinct a.phone
from users u
join updated_phone a on a.phone like concat(u.phone_no, '%')
where u.phone_no like '88%'
```

This query works fine.

Here is the query for updating phone number in users table

```
UPDATE u
SET u.phone_no=a.phone
FROM      updated_phone as a 
JOIN      users as u
         on a.phone like concat(u.phone_no, '%')
         where u.phone_no like '88%'
```

But this update query throwing error in syntax near **FROM**  and not updating values.
How to solve this syntax error and update information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `from` in `update` because the updating table is already defined in the `UPDATE` clause.

```
 UPDATE users as u
 JOIN   updated_phone as a    on a.phone like 'u.phone_no%'
 SET u.phone_no= a.phone
 where u.phone_no like '88%'
```

Comment: I have update the answer .. with join before set and i have also changed the like concat

Comment: I tried it before ,query executed but not updating values.  For better understanding my question is related to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953942/how-to-use-regexp-on-the-results-of-a-sub-query

Comment: You want match the phone number but not if begin with '88' ... i have update the answer ..adding '%u.phone_no%'

Comment: Any way the sintax error is solved then the question you posted is solved the rest is be related to another question

Comment: Code i wrote in question is okay. I provided the link to understand what i really want. Error is gone but i am not getting desired output yet. Please have a look what makes this query return without updating values.

Comment: I think your previous answer is correct . Please fix it and i'll mark it as completed :)

Comment: I have update the answer .. restoring the previous answer ..thank